# Use concrete viewResolver for concrete method

Tags: java, spring-mvc

For all methods I use my standard viewResolver:

```
 <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>
```

But for a method I want use another viewResolver(empty viewResolver).

How Can I make it for my method ?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logOut", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String logOut(Model model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute("message", "success logout");
        return "home.jsp";//I want forward to webapp/home.jsp
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of forwarding use a redirect and prefix the returned view with `redirect:`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logOut", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String logOut(RedirectAttributes redirect) throws Exception {
    redirect.addFlashAttribute("message", "success logout");
    return "redirect:/home.jsp";//I want forward to webapp/home.jsp
}
```

Something like that. The redirect/forward prefixes are explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting).

Comment: But it really to make that "message" doesn't appear in url string of browser?

Comment: Instead of the `Model` use `RedirectAttributes` for that. See modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

Return `View` or `ModelAndView` instead of `String`. Using these types, you can specify the view that you want to use, circumventing the view resolver.

Comment: Can you write example?